# Problem in magento installation

Tags: php, magento, wamp

HI
I am trying to install magento on my wamp server.

```
Have done settings in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts also.
```

Bt still getting error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on line 1125

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on line 1125

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on line 1125

Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line 151
```

Please help me.

Comment: Probably better asked on Magento's support forums

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look into D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on line 1125. Perhaps, also without knowledge of PHP, the name of the variables indicates what the problem can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advice to switch from WAMP to LAMP. Magento is not supported on Windows, and from my experience it really does strange things on this OS (hanging on index rebuilding, problems when porting modules to a production - linux - server, really slow working and some some other minor issues).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the dependencies for Magento installed. Make sure you have php-xml installed on your php installation.

While you are at it make sure you have gd installed as well.

You can check this by creating a php file with the following code in it and looking through it to find the different modules.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using 1.3, the magento developers guide has heaps of help using magento(including the different methods for the installation guide. You should be able to find a free copy somewhere. Otherwise a cheap purchase :)